# TextInputEditText view not rendering as expected

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

My problem is that `TextInputEditText` view does not expand to take up the entire width of the parent as I expect from using `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.
The code below is a snippet from the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditText1"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textInputLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout1">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditText2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_Percent="51"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="216dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine, but you likely are using an older version of `ConstraintLayout` (e.g. alpha 4). Try updating to the latest alpha 6, this will fix your issue (you will also need to replace `app:layout_constraintGuide_Percent="51"` by `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"` as there was an API change)

Answer (score 1):

Set the TextInputLayout element's width to match_parent

Comment: While this works, as soon I open the visual editor, it replaces `match_parent` with `0dp`, is this an intentional behaviour?

Comment: Try with this combination
android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: It has returned to being small

Comment: Can you set the element's width using the layout editor?

Comment: The widths I have put in are `0dp` for the TextInputLayout and `match_parent` for the TextInputEditText

Comment: Yet the widths I get from my device when I use Layout inspector for the TextInputEditText is 83px and for TextInputLayout is 646px

Comment: Maybe you should use another layout